# Access to DBContext within _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I want some code to execute on every page of my ASP .Net Core site.  It's primarily setting session variables.  I figured the best place to put it would be in _ViewStart.cshtml, but I don't have access to my dbcontext there.  So my question is two-fold -- first, am I doing the wrong thing, is there a better place to put this code so that it executes on every page of the site?  Second, how do I inject my dbcontext into _ViewStart.cshtml so I can do some database queries in the code there?

Comment: It is a bad idea to access your dbcontext directly from a view, my recomendation is, if you have variables you want to set once a user logs into your system, then just set them in that call (the login call in your controller), it's always better to just have and endpoint in your controller to do this kind of stuff and even have a DataAccessLayer to access your dbcontext. https://medium.com/net-core/repository-pattern-implementation-in-asp-net-core-21e01c6664d7

Comment: We're using AzureAD for login so there's no login controller to use.  Where should I put it?

Comment: @GeorgeHarris Can't you do this at your layout page ? Does this code needs to execute on every page refresh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Be sure your have imported the namespace of your DbContext in `_ViewImports.cshtml` like below:

```
@using YourProjectName.Data
```

2.Configure your `_ViewStart.cshtml` like below:

```
@inject MyDbContext _context;
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewBag.Context = _context;
}
```

3.Get the data in any razor view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    var data = ViewBag.Context as MyDbContext;
}

@data.Test.Select(u=>u.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

4.My testing model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

5.My testing DbContext:

```
namespace Mvc3_0.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you inject a call to a repository, for e.g.?